# How to find sundays between to dates without using any library

Tags: java, date

Hello i have a homework and i don't know how to do this

I have to find dates which is months firstday is sund between 1990 2000

Comment: You should make a function that checks what day it is on a given date. then you can simply evaluate that to sunday and loop between 1/1/1900 and 31/12/2000.

Comment: How can i make it ? i can't use any date or calendar library so i can't find what day it is on a given date.

Comment: You should count the no. of days that have elapsed from 1/1/1900 till the given date. Suppose x days have elapsed. Now you know it was Monday on 1/1/1900. Initialise String[] day {"Monday", "Tuesday", ..........."Sunday"}. Now day[x%7] will give you the desired day.

Comment: you mean i need to count the days when u say count the numbers?

Comment: Yeah but this does not provide me to find which months first day is sunday. It only help me to find how many sunday are there between two dates @AdityaArora

Comment: I dont think you understand. let me write code.

Comment: I would be very happy if you could help me, thanks for your interest.

Comment: @AdityaArora did you write ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
This is not a question. This is requirement for coding service which this site is not. You might want to visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Make some research, share some code & ask specific question if/when you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
class DayFinder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Note that if you enter a date below year 1901 you will get error
    String entereddate1 = "01-01-1990";
    String entereddate2 = "01-01-2022";
    
    int date1 = Integer.parseInt(entereddate1.substring(0,2));
    int month1 = Integer.parseInt(entereddate1.substring(3,5));
    int year1 = Integer.parseInt(entereddate1.substring(6,10));

    int date2 = Integer.parseInt(entereddate2.substring(0,2));
    int month2 = Integer.parseInt(entereddate2.substring(3,5));
    int year2 = Integer.parseInt(entereddate2.substring(6,10));
    
    for(int year = year1; year <= year2; year++)
        for(int month = month1; month <= 12; month++)
            if(getDay(1,month,year).equals("Sunday"))
                System.out.println("01-"+month+"-"+year+" is Sunday");
}

private static String getDay(int date, int month, int year) {

    String[] days_name = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    //Cumulative sum of days
    int[] month_days = {0,31,59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334};
    int days = (year - 1900-1) * 365 + month_days[month-1] + date + findLeapYears(year);

    return days_name[days%7];
}

//This find the number of leap of years from 1900 upto the year that is passed.
private static int findLeapYears(int year) {
    int leap_years = 0;
    for(int i = 1900; i <= year; i++) {
        if( ((i%4 == 0)  && (i%100 != 0)) || (i%400 == 0))
            leap_years += 1;
    }
    return leap_years;
}
}```
````

Comment: yes thank you for your interest but this is not exactly what i need. Because u used java.lang library first of all and this code is not primitive. And also i need to show the dates i have find like : 01.08.2021 i don't need to write day i have to show date

Comment: wait. java.lang library is imported to all programs implicitly

Comment: @Murat that is exactly what this does.

Comment: about _this code is not primitive_, this will even work in Java 1

Comment: But i couldn't see dates when i executed it. I just saw "Saturday" string. It must needed to show me months and years which are first day is sunday

Comment: Are you using blueJ?  Did you ran main method?

Comment: Im using intellij idea and yes i did run main method

Comment: Wait.  Let me see

Comment: @Murat edited. Works just as you truly desired

Comment: Yes now i saw it. I am really thankful to you!! I hope my teacher accept it because we used java.lang and she said i can't use any lib except IO but thank you so much!!

Comment: She will accept, though you should be prepared to explain this code to her.

Comment: @Murat Mark this as accepted if you got your answer